Filter out codes under certain conditions
I need to filter out codes beginning with 45XXX except code that equals 45003
using a where clause:
Select * from table where code NOT IN ('45%') 

will filter out all codes beginning with 45 including 45003 which I still want to include
Is there an easy way to do this?

...WHERE code NOT LIKE '45%' OR code = '45003'?

IN does not support wildcards, only LIKE does.

You could add an OR condition which whitelists the code 45003
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE code NOT LIKE '45%' OR code = '45003';


ah yes! Forget about the OR condition. Many thanks

If "code" column is numeric, this query can be better:
    SELECT *
      FROM myTable
     WHERE code between 45000 and 45999 and code<>45003;

